# What's the idiomatic name for a throwaway variable?

Tags: naming, syntax

[Velocity Template Language](http://click.apache.org/docs/velocity/vtl-reference-guide.html)'s set directive requires a variable on the left hand side. This doesn't work.

```
#set ( $entries.add("d") )
```

Even though I have no use for the return value of `add("d")`, I have to assign it to a variable.

```
#set ( $x = $entries.add("d") )
```

I want to communicate that the variable is necessary, but I have no intention of using it later. Is there a convention for naming variables that only exist to appease the compiler?

Comment: how about just using a comment

Comment: `foo`? [15 characters]

Comment: I would call it code smell.

Comment: Hi Patrick, variable naming questions are off-topic here: for more information, check out [Are “name that thing” questions on-topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/are-name-that-thing-questions-on-topic)

Comment: @Mark Okay, thanks. FWIW, I think this question leans more toward the "proper term for a concept" than "naming suggestions for a class or a method." I'm looking for an idiomatic name that would be used in various languages and codebases, not a specific name for a single variable.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Can you expand on your question to make that clearer? Right now, this question has attracted essentially a brainstorm session for possible variable names, which is the side of naming we really don't want here.

Comment: `$thisVariableOnlyExistsToAppeaseTheCompiler`

Comment: In my opinion this question is not **off topic**.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I tend to use `dummy` for this kind of situation (a variable that I *must* have though I don't need to use).

Comment: I always use ignored. I would have added my own answer but I couldn't think of anything else to say about that.

Comment: Besides dummy, I also use _ (some languages accept it), dump, junk, bhole (from black hole), useless, and some others names I don't recall right now.

Comment: +1 because after much searching, I discovered that by default, pylint ignores an unused variable named either "_" or "dummy". http://www.logilab.org/card/pylintfeatures#id9

Comment: And while searching for something else, found [a mention of $dummy specifically in Velocity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475144/437).

Answer (score 17):

You should check and see if your language has a name specifically for this use - Python has `_` that you should use for variables you intend to throw away.

Comment: Note that `_` is the traditional name for this kind of variable in languages that provide pattern matching (ML, Haskell, scala, etc.)

Comment: @barjak Good to know - I've never used any of those languages, I thought it was a Python thing

Answer (score 12):

**dummy**, **temp**, **trash**, **black_hole**, **garbage** ... any one of these tells me I won't be using them for anything.

If I do use if for something, I always rename the variable though.

Comment: +1 for renaming it if you do use it later.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question. I can think up plenty of names that say "this is not important." I'm looking for a single, standard name.

Comment: Except for a few newer languages, most of them don't have such. Such standard does not exist, if you don't consider the ones that gotten the most votes in here as "standard".

Answer (score 3):

You have plenty of good answers already, however I thought I'd toss one that's more directly related to velocity.

What is the add method returning?  If it's null you can simply tell velocity to quietly reference it:

```
$!entries.add("d")
```

However if you are replacing a value, and it returns the old value (like Map.put does), then you would need to set it to a dummy variable of some sort, if it's a void method, then you shouldn't need the variable at all.

If you're adamant about not using a new variable you could do the following:

```
#if($entries.add("d")) #end
```

If you're using it often enough I'd create a macro for it, then use it throughout your templates.  I don't see how useful that might be though, but at least you'd only need to comment it once...

Comment: Brilliant! The method returns `true` in this case ($entries is an ArrayList), but man, I wish that worked.

Comment: I was afraid that you were in fact referencing a list.  I've edited the answer to denote a way that you could go about not using a dummy variable, but I'm not so sure if I'd use it...

Answer (score 2):

I would give it a reasonable name and add a comment explaining that you are only assigning it to appease the compiler. I have seen cases where someone has used a variable name like `unused` and another developer has subsequently used that variable by that name and made an ugly mess of the code.

Comment: I like *unused* too. The only problem I have with it is the fact that I'm using it the moment I'm writing it :/